# How to replace every second occurrence of a word in a string

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I have a following problem to be solved in PowerShell - how do I replace every second occurrence of a string in a large string?

Example:

```
ReplaceEverySecond "AAAABAAAAAABAAAABAAABAA" "B" "x"
```

would become:

> "AAAAxAAAAAABAAAAxAAABAA"

I suspect the easiest would to construct a regular expression and to use the -replace function, but I cannot figure out how to construct the expression.

Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: I take it your to-be-replaced string could be more than one character in length?

Comment: Yup! Sorry I wasn't being clear on this.

Comment: In your example you change the first occurrence of 'B' and not the second one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume `"BA"` as the string to be replaced. Then you could use the regex

```
(BA(?:(?!BA).)*)BA((?:(?!BA).)*)
```

and replace with `\1xx\2`. This isn't limited to literal strings, you could also use a regex in place of `BA`.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xW8sL8/1).

**Explanation:**

```
(              # Start group 1
 BA            # Match BA (no. 1)
 (?:           # Match in non-capturing group:
  (?!BA)       # (unless it's at the start of "BA")
  .            # any character
 )*            # any number of times.
)              # End of group 1
BA             # Match BA (no. 2)
((?:(?!BA).)*) # and anything that follows until the next BA, if present.
```

Comment: example for powershell : `"fffbaffffbaffffbaffffbafff" -replace '(BA(?:(?!BA).)*)BA((?:(?!BA).)*)', '$1xx$2'`